# Cursor is not visible in EditText when view is dynamically added

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` and dynamically view is added in the layout. Whenever layout has a `EditText` cursor is not visible on `EditText` but it cursor is visible on top of the `EditText` which is `TextView`.

I added `onClick` event, XML file for both `Edittext` and `Textview` and XML file for the main layout.

My `textview` listener:

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        textView.setSelection(textView.getText().toString().length());
        textView.requestFocus();
        textView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        textView.setCursorVisible(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

XML file:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="@string/title_form_details"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TableLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/fieldsContainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:shrinkColumns="1"
                android:stretchColumns="1" >
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

`TextView` XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
     />
```

`EditText` XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
   android:textColor="#000000"
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
         />
```

Dynamically I am adding `TextView` and in next row I am adding `Edittext` view but whenever I clicked on `EditText`, cursor is visible on `TextView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this solution worked for me.

```
textView.setText("text");
textView.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             textView.setSelection(textView.getText().toString().length());
         }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are **setting the visibility of the cursor to textview**, So it is **visible** in TextView

**Remove** this line from your code

```
textView.setCursorVisible(true);
```

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    textView.setSelection(textView.getText().toString().length());
                    textView.requestFocus();
                    textView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                  //textView.setCursorVisible(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

and try to set the visiblity to **edittext**

```
    edittext .setCursorVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
textView.setCursorVisible(true);
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call setTextIsSelectable inside onTouchListener

```
 editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a   < requestFocus /> in your edittext. Maybe it works.

Comment: I tried that request focus is also not worked. Whenever I clicked on the edit text view cursor is visible in  text view.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is one of the silliest in Android, I guess...

Here is how I managed it:

```
  public void addEditText(LinearLayout linearLayout, final View view) {
    final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(editText);
    Utils.runDelayed(new Callable() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            if (editText.getText() == null || editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                editText.setText("");
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
                editText.setCursorVisible(true);
                editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, 10);
    editText.setTextAppearance(R.style.LargeEditText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}
```

The helper:

```
/**
 * Run delayed.
 *
 * @param callable the callable
 * @param delay    the delay
 */
public static void runDelayed(final Callable callable, long delay) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                callable.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, delay);
}
```